# Hide zoom options in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, zooming, hide

I have a chart as shown in the fiddle below

```
link: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/at8Lyod4/
```

where i need to remove the zoom option like 6m, YTD and 1y

[image]

how to remove the marked options?

Comment: Please add the JSFiddle link as a link, not code -- and since it asks you to add also your code then, add your code.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your options

```
rangeSelector: {
   enabled: false
},
```

[watch this](https://jsfiddle.net/hjm7L3yt/)

Comment: I need to disable only the marked options not all please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9gqzL216/4/